# javascript:insert data from database into html5 text field

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get data from `mysql` database in a `textfield` of html page. I am using `php` to take data from database and using `json` to give data to `javascript`. Then using id i am throwing value to `textfield`. But it is not working. I am easily getting the phone number in `div` or `li` tag using id but the same value does not appear in the `textfield`.

my javascript is like this

```
$('#tenantcontactTP').live('pageshow', function(event) {
var id = 'mukul_kuet@yahoo.com';
$.getJSON('tenantcontact.php?id='+id, displayEmployee);
});

function displayEmployee(data) {
var employee = data.item;

if (employee.TenantPhoneNumber) {
    $('#tphone').append(employee.TenantPhoneNumber);
}
}
```

Then my html page containing textfield is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="tenantcontactTP" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
<div data-role="content">    
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<form>
<table>
<tr><td>Phone Number</td><td><input type="text" name="tphone" id="tphone" value=""/></td></tr>
</table>
</ul>
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I will update phone number. Phone number is showing if i use list, but not showing in `text field`. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#tphone').val(employee.TenantPhoneNumber);` to add a value to the text field

Comment: not working bro!!before i can show in a list but now not in list nor in textfield.

Comment: Try replacing `$('#tenantcontactTP').live('pageshow', function(event)` with `$('#tenantcontactTP').live('pagecreate', function(event)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the input element's value, rather than appending. Use the following:

```
if (employee.TenantPhoneNumber) {
    $('#tphone').val(employee.TenantPhoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: not working bro!!before i can show in a list but now not in list nor in textfield

Comment: can u ppl use the proper wording: JavaScript and jQuery?